# Print function stops jquery post

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, http-post

I am working on a web application in codeigniter.  I am posting to controller using jquery post function and in the next line I am calling a print function. When I comment this print function jquery post is working fine, but otherwise jquery post is not working.

Am getting this error in chrome : Request headers caution provisional headers are shown

My Code:

```
$.post("<?=base_url()?>appointments/getAppointmentCount",  {'customer_code':customer_code}, function(data) {
alert("");
var appoCountObj = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(appoCountObj);
printbill();
});

function printbill()
{
/*print bill in popup*/
var printContent = $("#PreviewBillModal .modal-body").html();
var myWindow=window.open('', 'PrintWindow',   'width=950,height=850,top=50,left=50,toolbars=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,resizable=yes,minimizable=no');
myWindow.document.writeln('<!DOCTYPE html>');
myWindow.document.writeln('<html><head><title></title>');
myWindow.document.writeln("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='<?=base_url()?>css/style.css' />");
myWindow.document.writeln('</head><body>')
myWindow.document.write(printContent);
myWindow.document.writeln('</body></html>');

myWindow.document.close();
myWindow.focus();
myWindow.print();
myWindow.close();
}
```

Please help,
Thanks

Comment: What is the http status code on the request when doing this with an without print? The error you're seeing normally deals with the server side being wrong, not the client.

Comment: with commenting am getting status 200, with commenting am getting no status code, amm getting this error  "Request headers caution provisional headers are shown".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the print dialog stalls post. Try setting up a minor delay:

```
setTimeout(function() {      
  printbill();
},100);
```